# sql command not ended properly after executing the function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

for example I have created a table with table name 'aaa' with four columns act_num, clear_balance, available_balance, total_balance and I have inserted some values.

The function
deb_amount withdraws money from a bank account. It accepts an account
number and an amount of money as parameters. It uses the account number to
retrieve the account balance from the database, then computes the new balance. If this
new balance is less than zero then the function jumps to an error routine; otherwise,
it updates the bank account.

```
create or replace function deb_amount(p_act_num VARCHAR2, p_amount number ) 
return number as 

declare
v_old_amount number;
v_new_amount number;
e_over_drawn exception;

begin
select clear_balance into v_old_amount from aaa where act_num=p_act_num;
v_new_amount:=v_old_amount-p_amount;   
 if v_old_amount<p_amount then
        raise e_over_drawn;
            else
                update aaa set clear_balance=v_new_amount,available_balance=v_new_amount,total_balance=v_new_amount where act_num=p_act_num;
                end if;
                commit;
                return clear_balance;
        exception
        when e_over_drawn then
        rollback;
        end;
```

it will compile, but with warnings.

If I want to execute the 'select * from deb_amount(1,100)' it show error.
sql command not ended properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to call the function from the same script? What does `show errors` say? This may jusr be a formatting issue, but the create-submitting `/` character should be the first (and only) character on its line; if you really have it indented as the question shows, remove the indentation.

Comment: @Alex Poole. yes, I want to call this function 'select * from deb_amount(1,100)'. If I run this its shows error."sql command not ended properly."

Comment: You said that in your question; you haven't answered my query though. I don't know why you've now removed the `/`, does putting it at the start of the line help, and what does `show errors` (or querying `user_errors` ) say is wrong with the function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call function using dual. Ex:

```
select deb_amount(1,100) from dual;
```

or using a variable in plsql block

```
declare
  l_return number; 
begin 
  l_return:=deb_amount(1,100);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be running several commands as a scipt, but haven't ended the function properly. The `/` after the function creation has to be on a line on its own, and at the start of the line:

```
create or replace function deb_amount(p_act_num VARCHAR2,
  p_amount number) 
  return number as 
declare
  v_old_amount number;
  v_new_amount number;
  e_over_drawn exception;
begin
  select clear_balance into v_old_amount
  from aaa where act_num=p_act_num;
  v_new_amount:=v_old_amount-p_amount;   
  if v_old_amount<p_amount then
    raise e_over_drawn;
  else
    update aaa set clear_balance=v_new_amount,
      available_balance=v_new_amount,
      total_balance=v_new_amount
    where act_num=p_act_num;
  end if;
  commit;
  return clear_balance;
exception
  when e_over_drawn then
    rollback;
end;
/
show errors

select deb_account('1', 1) from dual;
```

The `show errors` will tell what actual compilation errors you got. It looks like it will complain about the `return` as you don't have a local `clear_balance` variable, but you can use `v_new_amount` instead here. You need to return something after the `rollback` too, or raise an exception which might be more useful.

As Manjunatha said, your query then needs to call the function properly, with the `from` clause referencing a table, rather than the function itself.

You have a bigger problem with the concept though; you can't call a function that does DML (insert, update, delete) from SQL, only from a PL/SQL block. Generally DML should be done from a procedure rather than a function, if it has to be done in PL/SQL at all.

Comment: as you said sir I'm new to this oracle. The concept is one account holder is having 1000$ and when he debit 100$, the clear, available and total balance has to be updated and when he wants to debit more than total_balance its should through exception. As you said I have to do in procedures. Plz dont mind sir, if I not answered your question

Comment: @suchithshivali - you aren't currently throwing an exception though, you're just silently rolling back. Even though you haven't performed an update in this function. You're commiting or rolling back anything previously done in the current session though, which may not be what you want - you shoudn't normally do either in a procedure/function, the caller should control the transaction state.

Comment: If I run the above function, its show "Warning: compiled but with compilation errors"

Comment: @suchithshivali - I've said three times already: do `show errors` to see the actual compilation errors. I've even told you what one of them is.